# Getting Serialization errors in Content Hub CLI

Tags: content-hub, serialization

I am trying to use `Content Hub CLI` for serialization so that I can pull items from dev and push those items into production.

I installed CH CLI using below command.

```
dotnet tool install --global --add-source https://slpartners.myget.org/F/m-public/api/v3/index.json ch-cli
```

Connected with my dev environment successfully using below command.

```
ch-cli endpoint add --name dev --url https://mydev.url/ --client-id <OAuth client ID> --client-secret <OAuth client secret>
```

But when I am trying to pull any taxonomy or any entity, it is giving me below error.

**`This feature is not supported in Content Hub version '4.1.14.471'. It was introduced in version '4.2.0.0'.`**
[image]

Same with pulling option lists.

But when I am trying to pull some action script, it successfully does that.

Command : `ch-cli scripting pull --name "XMP data"`

Does it not fully supported with Content Hub version 4.1? I did not find any sitecore document which says it supports only Content Hub version 4.2 and above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced challenges with this and understood that most of the operations are broken for CLI commands.

This is not fully supported by Content Hub and I have registered it as a bug/improvement with Sitecore with below reference numbers.

**MONE-37210 and  MONE-37211**

Note: This is considered by the product support team for implementation but not guaranteed that they will implement this in the near future, they can come up with an alternate solution also.

Comment: Thanks @Nikhi, I have also created a sitecore ticket for that. Will update on this ticket once I get any response.

Comment: Got the response from sitecore, added in the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Created a `sitecore` support ticket for that.

They confirmed that ch-cli does not support 4.1 because it is legacy version and tool is not designed for it. Support for 4.1 is limited to service availability. This has been described here:

https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1002729

So if want to take advantage of content hub cli, recommendation is to upgrade your instance to `content hub 4.2` or higher version.